# TailwindCSS breakpoints are not triggering when hitting certain breakpoints

Tags: css, next.js, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am working on a Next js + tailwindcss project, where I am trying to make my site responsive.

This is my component: `<div className="flex md:hidden">`

According to the rules, this div should start with its display set as flex, but as soon as it hits screen size "md" it should hide.

but it keeps itself hidden for some reason, and flex property never got applied.

Similarly, in 2nd case:

```
`<div className="bg-red-200 xs:bg-blue-500 sm:bg-pink-600 md:bg-green-400 lg:bg-gray-50"`
```

only background color of "md" screen size is applied for every screen size while testing.

I tried custom values as well but it didn't solve anything, here is my `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'xs': '320px',
      'sm': '576px',
      'md': '960px',
      'lg': '1440px',
      'xl': '1280px',
      '2xl': '1536px',
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I have gone through docs, many StackOverflow questions & Youtube videos but I don't have any idea why this is happening, please help me find its cause, Thanks.

Comment: it happens because it's not max display but minimum so if you use md it will affect lg and md display, i had the same problem, and the solution i found was using max-md

Answer (score 1):

it happens because it's not max display but minimum so if you use md it will affect lg and md display, i had the same problem, and the solution i found was using max-md

```
md:hidden
```

to

```
max-md:hidden
```

using max makes it only work up to that display

Comment: It didn't work bro

Comment: try sm then, see the max px every screen